# When a number is in the cell, count it in a column that matches column header

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm currently trying to work on a macro that will look for grades and count assignments done. It works...for the most part...But I'm having some trouble with it being very static. I've hardcoded a specific range, but I need it to be dynamic, in case more/less columns are in the spreadsheet or if columns not related to grades are added at the end (such as Finalized). My coworker may need Math/History/Science Grade 4 or 5 or 6. You get the idea.

Before macro is run:
[image]

After macro is run:
[image]

```
Sub CreateGrades()
Dim TempString As String
TempString = ""

Application.ScreenUpdating = False ' Ensure we aren't spamming the graphics engine

Dim TheLastRow As Long
TheLastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

Columns("G:G").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight ', CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

Columns("H:H").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

Columns("I:I").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

Columns("G:G").Select
TempString = "IF(AND(ISNUMBER(RC[4]), RC[4]>0),""1,"","""")&IF(AND(ISNUMBER(RC[7]), RC[7]>0),""2,"","""")&IF(AND(ISNUMBER(RC[10]), RC[10]>0),""3,"","""")"
Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(LEN(" + TempString + ") > 0, LEFT( " + TempString + ", LEN( " + TempString + " ) - 1 ), " + TempString + " )"
Columns("G:G").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Range("G1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Math"

Columns("H:H").Select
TempString = "IF(AND(ISNUMBER(RC[4]), RC[4]>0),""1,"","""")&IF(AND(ISNUMBER(RC[7]), RC[7]>0),""2,"","""")&IF(AND(ISNUMBER(RC[10]), RC[10]>0),""3,"","""")"
Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(LEN(" + TempString + ") > 0, LEFT( " + TempString + ", LEN( " + TempString + " ) - 1 ), " + TempString + " )"
Columns("H:H").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Range("H1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "History"

Columns("I:I").Select
TempString = "IF(AND(ISNUMBER(RC[4]), RC[4]>0),""1,"","""")&IF(AND(ISNUMBER(RC[7]), RC[7]>0),""2,"","""")&IF(AND(ISNUMBER(RC[10]), RC[10]>0),""3,"","""")"
Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(LEN(" + TempString + ") > 0, LEFT( " + TempString + ", LEN( " + TempString + " ) - 1 ), " + TempString + " )"
Columns("I:I").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Range("I1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Science"

' Draw borders around the maps, and shade/color the cells
Call HighlightAllDataMaps(TheLastRow)

' Draw the legend at the top
Call DrawInstructions("AllData")

ActiveSheet.name = "All Grades"

' If we aren't already filtering, then turn it on
If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False Then
    [a3].Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
End If

Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.Activate
With Selection.Font
    .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With

Rows("1:1").Select
With ActiveWindow
    .SplitColumn = 0
    .SplitRow = 1
End With
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True

End Sub
```

One idea I had was to use COUNTIFS to look for columns that have Math, Science, and History, but I know that impacts the code dramatically. I did try it with my current code, just to see if it'd work. It does work, but it took my macro 6 minutes to run! I switched out the current TempString for the following:

```
TempString = "IF(COUNTIFS(R1C[4],""*Math*"", RC[4], "">0""),""1,"","""")&IF(COUNTIFS(R1C[7],""*Math*"", RC[7], "">0""),""2,"","""")&IF(COUNTIFS(R1C[10],""*Math*"", RC[10], "">0""),""3,"","""")&IF(COUNTIFS(R1C[13],""*Math*"", RC[13], "">0""),""4,"","""")&IF(COUNTIFS(R1C[16],""*Math*"", RC[16], "">0""),""5,"","""")&IF(COUNTIFS(R1C[19],""*Math*"", RC[19], "">0""),""6,"","""")&IF(COUNTIFS(R1C[22],""*Math*"", RC[22], "">0""),""7,"","""")&IF(COUNTIFS(R1C[25],""*Math*"", RC[25], "">0""),""4,"","""")"
```

That gets around the issue of non-Grade columns getting counted, but performance really takes a hit. My mind is spent. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using an array equation, the processing speed becomes slow if there is a lot of data. It is better to assign values than to use formulas.

Ty,

```
Sub CreateGrades()
    Dim TempString As String
    Dim vDB As Variant, vR() As Variant
    Dim rngDB As Range
    Dim r As Long, i As Long
    Dim j As Integer, k As Integer, n As Integer
    Dim s As String

    TempString = ""
    
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False ' Ensure we aren't spamming the graphics engine
    
    Dim TheLastRow As Long
    TheLastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Range("g:i").Insert
    Range("g1").Resize(1, 3) = Array("Math", "History", "Science")
    
    
    Set rngDB = Range("a1").CurrentRegion
    
    vDB = rngDB
    
    r = UBound(vDB, 1)
    c = UBound(vDB, 2)
    
    For i = 2 To r
        For j = 7 To 9
            n = 0
            Erase vR
            For k = 10 To c
                If vDB(i, k) <> "" Then
                    s = vDB(1, k) 'Grade 1 Math  or Math Grade 1
                    If InStr(s, vDB(1, j)) Then
                        s = Trim(Replace(s, vDB(1, j), ""))
                        n = n + 1
                        ReDim Preserve vR(1 To n)
                        vR(n) = Right(s, 1)
                    End If
                End If
            Next k
            If n Then
                vDB(i, j) = Join(vR, ",")
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    rngDB = vDB
'' Draw borders around the maps, and shade/color the cells
'Call HighlightAllDataMaps(TheLastRow)
'
'' Draw the legend at the top
'Call DrawInstructions("AllData")
'
'ActiveSheet.Name = "All Grades"
'
'' If we aren't already filtering, then turn it on
'If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False Then
'    [a3].Select
'    Selection.AutoFilter
'End If
'
'Rows("1:1").Select
'Selection.Activate
'With Selection.Font
'    .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
'    .TintAndShade = 0
'End With
'
'Rows("1:1").Select
'With ActiveWindow
'    .SplitColumn = 0
'    .SplitRow = 1
'End With
'ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much. Where did you learn how to get so good at VBA? I would love to know the resources. If my coworker decides to change the naming convention to say Grade 1 Math, Grade 2 Math, etc, is that an easy change?

Comment: @JerrySeinfeld, It works normally when Math Grade 1 , Math Grade 2: but you need to know how to change the actual data to apply the solution.

Comment: @JerrySeinfeld,  i edited answer. Grade 1 Math or Math Grade 1 ,I changed it to possible in both cases.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much.